# How to display value over the bar while tap on bar in Bar chart using ios charts?

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts, bar-chart, ios-charts

I am trying to display selected bar value in bubble [like this](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/78b4bc4e50e151970961daf56e81c4c0db72d27c/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f5068696c4a61792f4d5043686172742f6d61737465722f73637265656e73686f74732f73696d706c6564657369676e5f6261726368617274332e706e67) while tap on Bar.
I have implemented `chartView.drawMarkers = true;` as suggested but still while i tap on particular bar its not shows value in bubble as shown in the image.

Please help me i stuck here.
My coding language is `objective-c` not `swift`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you implemented the chart marker and assign it to chart view? Check out ChartsDemo's line chart view controller:

```
BalloonMarker *marker = [[BalloonMarker alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:180/255. alpha:1.0] font:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0] insets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(8.0, 8.0, 20.0, 8.0)];
marker.minimumSize = CGSizeMake(80.f, 40.f);
_chartView.marker = marker;
```

Comment: Hey Wingzero Thanks for answer but i have a question that
From where i will get BalloonMarker class ? its not in ios-charts.

Comment: it's in chartsDemo code, I only show you the example, you need to adopt it

Comment: Thanks a lot Wingzero Thank you very much for your valuable answer.

Comment: Hi  Wingzero one more question want to ask you.
Can we change marker's(Buuble) image ? and marker's value type from float to int or string ?

Comment: marker base class already has image property, you could use it. The value you want to display is also your call. just take a look at marker code, should be easy

Comment: Thanks @Wingzero you save my day, please help me i wanna saw marker without touchup how to do?